# Creating a report via Salesforce Report API

Tags: rest-api, reporting, reports-api

I want to programmatically create a report with several filters, and I'm not sure how to correctly do this via Report API.

Note : The report type (objects returned in the report) are dynamically chosen by the user, so I don't know in advance whether this is going to be a report on Leads \ Opportunities \ Accounts \ Custom object etc.

My options as far as I see :

- Use the [QUERY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_report_query.htm) method to run a report - but then, how can I save this report for later use? (Documentation says it's not saved)
- Create a dummy report manually, then use [PATCH](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_list_resource.htm) method to change an existing report - tried this, but it seems I cannot change the reportType field (I get an error saying "INVALID COLUMN" when trying to change an Opportunities report  to a Leads Report)

Am I missing something?

Comment: An Opportunities Report will have different fields in it than a Leads Report.

Comment: You're right, but even after changing both list of columns and report types I get this error.

Comment: I think you need Metadata API - metadata type = Report; see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm and also the Apex wrapper to the metadata API. However, running user will need Setup and Change application permissions which would not be a good idea.  Why not just use Dynamic SOQL and VF?